# how PE MexE profile element exists in Profile Package is it comes inside GenericFileManagement because there is no Template for this PE

Tags: e-sim

in TCA specification for profile interoperability 2.3 there is no template for PE MexE so how this element will come inside Profile Package.

is it coming like separated element like this?

```
{'fileManagementCMD': [[{'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '14',
     'fileDescriptor': '4221000a',
     'fileID': '5f3c',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '10',
     'fileDescriptor': '4121',
     'fileID': '4f40',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '850431323334'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '4121',
     'fileID': '4f41',
     'pinStatusTemplateDO': '010a',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f42',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f43',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f44',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f45',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f46',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'}]],
 'gfm-header': {'identification': 98, 'mandated': None}}
```

is it coming with LinkPath to Usim ADF like this

```
{'fileManagementCMD': [[{'linkPath': 7f01},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '10',
     'fileDescriptor': '4121',
     'fileID': '4f40',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '850431323334'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '4121',
     'fileID': '4f41',
     'pinStatusTemplateDO': '010a',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f42',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f43',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f44',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f45',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'},
   {'createFCP': {'efFileSize': '20',
     'fileDescriptor': '42210010',
     'fileID': '4f46',
     'securityAttributesReferenced': '2f0602',
     'shortEFID': ''}},
   {'fillFileContent': '1122334455667788990011223344556611223344556677889900112233445566'}]],
 'gfm-header': {'identification': 98, 'mandated': None}}
```

if the PE doesnt have Template how it will be come inside esim profile package.

like PE MexE, PE Wlan and so on.